# How did Cooper and team know that the water is shallow?

Tags: interstellar

In Interstellar, how did they know that the water on Miller's planet would be shallow just before landing, when they clearly didn't know that the entire planet was covered in water in the first place?
Also, what would have happened if the planet wasn't shallow and was actually as deep as oceans?

Comment: Maybe they saw the wreckage of the other ship. But I would think they would have floated either way, since they were "floating" while riding the wave.

Comment: I don't have the script or anything so I can't say what their excuse was, but I'm sure they had ground radar and other tools that could tell the water was shallow. Plus they're following the scientist's beacon and they knew/assumed the scientist would have set up camp in an appropriate place.

Comment: @Rijumone, do you want a canon source or will a plausible explanation serve?  If the latter, I recommend Robert Wertz promote his comment to an answer.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks how did they "know" they would float?

Comment: @Rijumone: It's possible the craft is made to float, and they would know that much.

Comment: Related: [How was Cooper confident about landing his Ranger on Miller's planet?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/60659/49)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the [official novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21488063-interstellar), they added an additional line of dialogue to suggest that Brand was monitoring some kind of remote sensor, possibly an active radar of some description.

> Cooper banked as hard as he could, trying to shed more speed. The
> surface was coming fast.
>
> **“It’s shallow,” Brand said. “Feet deep…”**
>
> ...
>
> The retro-rockets kicked in just above the surface, punching back
> against their velocity. He tried to hold it, but the craft slewed
> sideways as the landing gear came down. They dropped, hit the water,
> casting up a spray. The impact nearly jarred Cooper’s teeth loose, but
> he held on stubbornly. Then when the air cleared, they were down, and
> everything looked good. **Brand had been right — the water was really,
> really shallow — so much so that the landing gear held the Ranger just
> above the surface.**

---

This line is also found in the [final draft screenplay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4C9FN_1M1sxVFpHRTlaYmxSdzA/view#_=_). Presumably it was simply cut in editing.

> **DOYLE :** *Just water.*
>
> **BRAND :** *The stuff of life ..*.
>
> **CASE :** *Twelve hundred meters out.*
>
> Cooper BANKS sharply, eases down.
>
> **BRAND :** **It's shallow. Feet deep ...**
>
> EXT. MILLER'S PLANET - CONTINUOUS
>
> The Ranger is low now, kicking up backwash

---

In the film itself, we (and presumably Cooper) can see that the downthrust is penetrating all the way to the sea bed:

[image]

Comment: Ah good to know... I think it adds more drama wondering if they are going to plunge into the abyss with every step they took running around in that water.